# How to change font size of sub child element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have html like below

```
<span id="3072" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 1898px; height: 194px; ">
     <div style="visibility: visible; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 90.5px; width: 1898px;">
         <div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8.25pt; font-style: normal;>
         </div>
     </div>
</span>
```

here I want to change `font-size:8.25pt` to `14pt` from the last div tag, how do I access contents of the last div tag using id from span tag.

I can easily change the contents of the 1st div tag something like below

```
document.getElementById("3072").firstChild.fontize="14px";
```

But in this case the Div tags doesn't have any classes or Id's to access them.

Anyone has any thoughts on this please share.

Image attached which shows the code of the html.

Thanks.

Comment: you are missing a " at the end of the style attribute of the second div.

Comment: use jquery's `eq`

Comment: native javascript solution: [queryselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: `$('span  div').last().css("font-size", "14px");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a class or id directly to your target element, but if you can not change the markup then you can use:-

use `querySelector`

```js
document.querySelector('[id="3072"]>div>div').style['font-size'] = '14px';
```

```html
<span id="3072" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 1898px; height: 194px; ">
     <div style="visibility: visible; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 90.5px; width: 1898px;">
         <div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8.25pt; font-style: normal;">
           14px
         </div>
     </div>
</span>
```

or jQuery

```js
$('#3072>div>div').css('font-size', '14px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="3072" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 1898px; height: 194px; ">
  <div style="visibility: visible; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 90.5px; width: 1898px;">
    <div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8.25pt; font-style: normal;">
      14px
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

**Note**: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) about using numbers as id's.

Comment: May I know how to add class to directly to the target element.